# Interface for my router in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, interface, routing

I would like to know if there is a way in which I can create an **interface** in my **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop** for my router. 
**My Goal:** I want to `tcpdump` the **ip address of the router** which is 192.168.1.1.

```
new-eth1-for router     HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
                        inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255


eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:68:36:aa:05  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

As you can see in the table above 
My computer : 192.168.1.101
My router : 192.168.1.1
Localhost : 127.0.0.1 (I need it for MySQL and PHP)

I just want to know if there is a way to work this "monitoring" thing. If anybody has another suggestion or solution, please do not hesitate, I just want to hear a hint.

Thank you
My regards

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you tell us what you want to achieve, maybe we can help you.

Comment: @JavierRivera I think he's trying to pipe the router through his computer for monitoring purposes. AFAIK, what he's attempting won't work as it creates a duplicate IP of the router on the network.

Comment: @JavierRivera My Goal: I want to tcpdump the ip address of the router which is 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this can't be done.  Your router is a completely separate device.  You'd have to have the tcpdump program, or similar, actually running on the router.

There are plenty of software router implementations, some of which may do this for you already.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_or_firewall_distributions

Or, you may have a router that supports DD-WRT, which is Linux.  You can install tcpdump on such installations.. here's an example.

http://emtunc.org/blog/04/2011/installing-tcpdump-on-dd-wrt-wrt54gl/